# How to access same class text present in two different div's

Tags: jquery

I have got two div's by name **myordersfinal** and **swiper-pages**

Both of the above div's has got a common  class by name **additions**

under swiper-pages div

```
<b class="additions">145.00</b>
```

under myordersfinal  div is

```
<b class="additions">245.00</b>
```

The way i am accessing the class additions text is by using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var vendoritemid = '789';
var currentadditionsprice = parseFloat($("#lastwrap" + vendoritemid+'.lastItm_Wrapcommon').find('.Itm_right_aside .additions').text());
alert(currentadditionsprice);
});
```

Is there a way to access additions  value using jquery selector  **not** ??

For example , if i want to access the additions value under **swiper-pages** div and not **myordersfinal**

I tried this way ,

```
var currentadditionsprice = parseFloat($("#lastwrap" + vendoritemid+'.lastItm_Wrapcommon').find('.Itm_right_aside .additions .not("#myordersfinal")').text());
```

please let me know if this is possible using not class ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/5681/

Comment: Thanks , I am getting NAN , this is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/5683/

Comment: Can you write your HTML code structure in your question?

Comment: maybe it could help : :not(selector)  $("input:not(:empty)")  All input elements that are not empty [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 3):

With JQuery :

```
var currentadditionprice = $('#swiper-pages .additions').text();
```

or pure javascript :

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#swiper-pages .additions');
var currentadditionprice = elem.textContent;
```

**EDIT**:

textContent is not supported by IE 8. An alternative would be innerText, a non-standard property supported by IE **BUT** not supported by Firefox until version 45.

Source: http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=innertext

Comment: To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentadditionsprice = $("#swiper-pages .additions").html();
```

> html() :  This method uses the browser's innerHTML property

will this work ?

Comment: I need the value that is 145.00

Comment: is it possible to use not selector ??